# How to limit player activity?

Tags: java, game-physics

I have a simple game where a player shoots some bullets. However, I want to make it so that the player can only shoot a bullet every x seconds. How would I do this?

I have tried to do it by taking the average time between bullets and saying that if average time is less than one second don't let the space bar (the control for shooting) work. However, I don't know how to make the space bar not work, AND that would mean a player could just not shoot for a wile and then shoot a lot of bullets at once.

The method for shooting looks something like this:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (!keysDown.contains(e.getKeyCode()))
        keysDown.add(new Integer(e.getKeyCode()));
```

This adds the integer of the key value to an array, which is then read here:

```
if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)) {
        b = new Bullets(x);
        bullCount.add(b);
        System.out.println(bullCount.get(0).getY());
        System.out.println ("There are " + bullCount.size() + "bullets alive.");
        //elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
        //if ((elapsed / bulletCount) < 1000000000) {


       //this is where I would say 'no more bullets shot until 
       //average time in   nanoseconds is more than 1 second!' but I don't know how


        //}
```

Comment: You should put some logic/Pseudocode what you have tried.

Comment: Without your code we cannot do much. One way to do is to compare the times the player last shot with the current time, so you can determine the time that has been passed. However this does not works ultimately and you should have some sort of timer to do it.

Comment: I put some code in, sorry.

Comment: Take a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a global variable ie: `long lastShot`. 
When user shot, check if `(System.currentTimeMilis()-lastShot>5000)` before you allow him to shoot. 
If it is ok to shoot, store the `lastShot = System.currentTimeMilis();` and do the real shot. 
If not, don't allow him to shoot. 
Here is an example in pseudo-code:

```
class SomeClass {
   private long lastShot;

   public void userPressedShot() {
       if (System.currentTimeMillis()-lastShot>5000) {
            lastShot = System.currentTimeMillis();
            doTheRealShot(); 
       }       
       // Ignored till 5000 miliseconds from last shot
   }

}
```

Comment: I'd love to vote it up, but I'm three rep short. I've only been on this website for a short period of time.

Comment: Use `System.nanotime()` rather than `System.currentTimeMillis()`: you want to compute arbitrary time difference, not compare this second to the next one.

Answer (score 2):

One overkill option is to use the Guava's RateLimiter

```
final RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(2.0); // rate is "2 permits per second"
while(true) {
     rateLimiter.acquire();
     shootSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this solution I assume that you use a `Player` Object.
It's very simple:

1.: add the field `lastShot` of the type `long` with the value 0 to your class.

2.: Whenever the player shoots, set lastShot to `System.currentTimeMillis()`

3.: Now, before you let him shoot, check if `System.currentTimeMillis()-lastShot` is smaller than your bullet delay in seconds.

This would be a MWE which has to be inserted in your player class:
Just call the Method `player.shoot()` to let him shoot - or not, if it's not possible.

```
private long lastShot = 0;
//return value is for you to check if the shot happened
public boolean shoot(){
    //Did the last shot happen less than 1 second (1000 milliseconds) ago
    if(System.currentTimeMillis()-lastShot <= 1000){
        //If yes: return false, the shot can not happen
        return false;
    }else{
        lastShot = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //If no: insert your shooting code here to be executed

        //return true, the shot happened
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a timer that resets every second the bullets count :

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        bullCount.clear();
    }
}, 0, 1000); // 0 is the delay in milliseconds before it starts and 1000 is the time in milliseconds between successive task executions
```

Then when a player wants to shoot you just have to look at bullCount's size